# Katex not working in Firefox on dynamically created formulas

Tags: firefox, katex

I have math delimiters wrapped in `span`.
Therefore, before rendering math, I unwrap delimiters and then render math.
This works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.
Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/2zk3su9w/

Answer (score 0):

We need to call normalize before rendering math: `container.normalize();`.